# Parse.Query get() fails to retrieve object

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am unable to retrieve a PFUser object using its objectId. I always get an "Object not found" error.

I do not understand why this is happening. When I log userObjectUniqueID to the console I can see that it's the exact objectId for the PFUser I'm trying to retrieve. From what I understand from the documentation, this should give me object that belongs to the objectId.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("myFunction", function(request, response){
    var userObjectUniqueID = request.params.userUniqueID; //Unique object ID for the user object.

    var UserClass = Parse.Object.extend("User"); //Referencing the user class.
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(UserClass);

    userQuery.get(userObjectUniqueID, {
        success: function(user){
            alert("Query was successful.")
        },
        error: function(object, error)
        {
            alert("query failed: " + error.message);
        }
    })

});
```

I've also tried to use the find() function in Parse.Query to retrieve the PFUser object. Even though I've used the appropriate constraints, it still won't return the object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You've made a common mistake, in that the internal classes "User", "Role" and "Installation" have special names (prefixed with an underscore).

The preferred way to do it is:

```
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
```

You can also use "_User" as the class name if you need to extend, though the above is preferred.